# CSOAP for C Application

Tags: web-services

I am working on a C application which uses [CSOAP](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/) for web services. I have a couple of questions on that. First can anyone please explain what **url**, **urn**, **method** are in [this](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs/snapshot/libsoap-doc-api/html/) soap client example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean this example: http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs/snapshot/libsoap-doc-api/html/csoap_client_page.html

`url` is the HTTP endpoint to which the message will be sent.
`urn` is the namespace which the XML elements will be prefixed.
`method` is the SOAP method which will be specified in the SOAP envelope.